# How to pack existing database in iphone DocumentDirectory instead of resourcePath

Tags: iphone

I want to pack my big database with iphone app and I don't want to copy a database from resource path to document directory for readonly problem. It's have other way to pack database to document directory or remove database from resource path after copy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

why not put your big database in your web server.

when your application first start, to make a initialized request to this database ,
and download it .save it in your document directory.