# Consideration: Leave Read-only DB in Application resourcePath or copy to documents/library folder

Tags: iphone, sqlite, resources

My App uses a read-only sqlite db. Now I am unsure, if it makes *any sense* to copy the db to the documents or library folder on the iphone or to leave it in the applications bundle (`[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]`).

Are there known issues with leaving the db in the resourcePath besides that it can only be used read only (e.g. is unpacking data an issue as the app itself is stored as a zip container and therefore frequent access is not recommended...)?

(There is a [similar unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406710/how-to-pack-existing-database-in-iphone-documentdirectory-instead-of-resourcepath), but my main point is the access of the db in the resource folder, not manipulating the resource folder.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None I'm aware of. I would let the DB in the resource folder, save some space and prevent iTunes to include that db in every backup.

Comment: The backup remark is a good point. As I am not accessing the db continuously, I tend to agree to store it in the resource folder. I will leave the question open for some days before marking it answered. Thanks.